# Не работают операторы break & continue

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, где в этом коде ошибка

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = new Array(2, 5, 7);

    var b = new Array();

    while (true) {
        var x = prompt("vashe chislo", "0");

        x = +x;

        if (x == 0) {
            break
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == 0) {
                b[i] = "-";

                continue;
            }
            b[i] = x / a[i];
        }
        alert(+a "\n" ("+x+")"\n" + b);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: может потому что выполняется условие?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=new Array(0,5,7);
var b=new Array();
while(true){
    var x=prompt("Ваше число:", "0");
    x=+x;
    if(x==0){break;}
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i]==0){
            b[i]="-";
            continue;
        }
        b[i]=x/a[i];
    }
    alert(a+"\n"+"+x+"+"\n"+b);
}
</script>
```

Помоему так работают

Comment: `alert(a+"\n"+x+"\n"+b);` скорей всего так запланировано!

Comment: супер, спасибо что помог